# Checkbox condition in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to hide all products that are not checked.
for example:- I have a checkbox button in product.template model and i want to hide hide all those products that are unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

each and every model have active field , by default active=True, so you can create separate view which product not active. you can refer active field for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can archive products that you don't want to show particular product.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved by adding domain field in action window by following code:-

```
<record id="action_product_pack_view" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">product pack</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('is_pack','=',True)]</field>
```